# Conditional Expectation of Two Dice Roll?

Tags: expectation, dice, conditional-expectation

A is the first roll of the dice, B is the second.

The question is to find the expected value of A given A + B = 7; E(A|A+B = 7)

Since A can be any number between 1 and 6, is this as simple as (1/6)*1 + (1/6)*2 + (1/6)*3 + (1/6)*4 + (1/6)*5 + (1/6)*6?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, B can be 6 different things

It can be 1,2,3,4,5, or 6

Each of these only has one value of A that makes A+B=7, right?

A+B=7 can be rewritten as A=7-B, which shows that each possibility of B gives 1 A

If B is random, then so is A.

If A could be 6,5,4,3,2, or 1, then what is the average if it is randomly chosen?

TL;DR, your answer is correct, and I presume that the method you used to get there was too.

Answer (score 0):

Well! The expected sum when 2 dice are rolled =7. So even if it is not given that A+B=7, still we already assume as it is the expected value. So the ans is same as that when you roll a die which is 3.5

Comment: It's the right numerical answer, but I don't follow your argument.